# Using OpenLayers in react's create-react-app to render map.Getting following error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, openlayers, openlayers-3, create-react-app

**To include OpenLayers i did**: 
npm install ol --save

and implemented as follows:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import 'ol/ol.css';
    import ol from 'ol';
    import Map from 'ol/map';
    import View from 'ol/view';
    import Tile from 'ol/layer/tile';


    class MapComponent extends Component {

        componentDidMount() {
            var map = new ol.Map({
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: [0, 0],
                    zoom: 1
                }),
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    })
                ],
                target: 'map'
            });
        }
        render() {

            return (
                <div id="map"></div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default MapComponent;
```

**ERROR**:Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ol**.a.View is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have imported View separately from ol. You should probably try using:

`view: new View({...`

Same would go for Map on the line above.

Comment: Thanks.it did work by changing ol.View to View,but if i don't import Map,View and Tile separately from ol.The error persists.

Comment: Importing them separately seems like the right thing to do. It just seems like an ambiguity in the ol code samples. Import them but don't prepend the ol when you use the constructor.